# How to disable multiple select on lists in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, list-view, list-item

thank you for reading my question!

I have a little problem with lists in Sharepoint 2010. The goal is to disable the checkboxes on the left of each item, but to keep them selectable.

I know that it's possible to disable the checkboxes at all in the view settings (Modify View -> Tabular View -> Allow individual item checkboxes). But when I do this the items are not selectable any more.

Thank you very much!

LMW

Comment: The whole purpose of these checkboxes is to select the items. I'm a bit unclear as to how else you expect to be able to select the rows?

Comment: Can you give an outline of what you're trying to achieve? It may help us give you a better suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to accomplish this, you can use client side scripting to convert the behavior of the check boxes to radio buttons (i.e. a user clicks a check box, all others are deselected).

I just ran a test where I hide all the check boxes using JavaScript, but doing so prevented me from making any selections...so the check boxes need to stay, but there's no reason you can't limit the number of selected check boxes to 1.